# Resque/Redis performing job

Tags: php, redis, queue, resque

I'm using PHP Resque library to create PHP jobs https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque

I can create a job successfully, but when I need to run the job (perform it) it is just loading.

Here is my worker:

```
    $worker = new Resque_Worker("0c129873b7c4ee43e8c7799c37cab4be");
    $worker->work(5, true);
```

This is class handling the job:

```
class PHP_Job
{
    public function perform()
    {
        file_put_contents("t.txt", "test text");
    }
}
```

This is how I create job:

```
$jobId = Resque::enqueue("test", "PHP_Job", $args, true);
echo "Queued job ".$jobId."\n\n";
```

When I run worker it is just loading, I'm not sure how to run queued job.

**EDIT**

I started worker and it says what is on the picture, but nothing else is happening. File is not being created.
[image]

Comment: [SOLUTION] It's working, I only had to use files from version 1.2
https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-resque/releases
and I followed this tutorial http://kamisama.me/2012/10/12/background-jobs-with-php-and-resque-part-4-managing-worker/